# timezone conversion in pyspark

Tags: python-3.x, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

i have data in the following format

[image]

like "IN" in the country column, i have various APAC countries and i want to convert the dates in "created_date" column to respective Asian countries (china, japan, singapore etc...) local time.

following is the code i wrote to do it.

```
avaya = avaya.withColumn('datetime_LocalTime', F.when(F.col('country') == 'NZ', F.from_utc_timestamp(F.col('created_date'), 'Pacific/Auckland')).otherwise(
    F.when(F.col('country') == 'AU', F.from_utc_timestamp(F.col('created_date'), 'Australia/Canberra')).otherwise(
        F.when(F.col('country').isin('KR', 'JP'), F.from_utc_timestamp(F.col('created_date'), 'Japan')).otherwise(
            F.when(F.col('country').isin('CN', 'SG', 'MY', 'PH'), F.from_utc_timestamp(F.col('created_date'), 'Asia/Singapore')).otherwise(
                F.when(F.col('country').isin('ID', 'VN', 'TH'), F.from_utc_timestamp(F.col('created_date'), 'Asia/Ho_Chi_Minh')).otherwise(
                    F.when(F.col('country').isin('IN'), F.from_utc_timestamp(F.col('created_date'), 'Asia/Kolkata')).otherwise(
                        F.lit(None)
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    )
))
```

i have 2 questions here, the created date is in the following format - YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS.000Z, i assumed it is in UTC and did this conversion

1. how do i confirm weather this format "YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS.000Z" is actually UTC or not
2. if its not UTC how do i parse this to different countries timezone?

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR, it is UTC.

The Z in the date stands for the [Zulu Timezone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#:%7E:text=Coordinated-,Universal,-Time%20(UTC)%5B) which has no offset from UTC.